# Showing that the negative binomial PMF is valid

Tags: probability, summation

Let $X\sim\text{NegBin}(m,p)$ where $P[X=n]={n-1\choose m-1}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}$ for $n\geq m$.

I want to verify that

$$\sum_{n=m}^\infty{n-1\choose m-1}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}=1$$

but it's not easy to see how I should approach this sum.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is related to the binomial series with negative index. See, e.g.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Extension_to_real-valued_r